# How to improve Highcharts setExtremes performance with a ton of data?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a page making use of Highcharts' highstock.js and boost.js. There is one chart (minus the navigator) however that one chart consists of 200 yAxes. And each yAxes has 30,000 data points. We're attempting to advance the chart slowly every second. However, we're finding that the call to setExtremes for the chart is slow...sometimes horribly slow (particularly in Chrome). So the chart does not appear to move in real-time (we're dealing with datetime data).

https://jsfiddle.net/Eves/kapnLbwh/288/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
  <button id="add">Set Extremes</button>
  <div id="container" style="height: 4000px; min-width: 500px"></div>
  <button id="addTwo">Set Extremes</button>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var totalCharts = 200.0;

var data = [];
var time = (new Date()).getTime();

for (var i = 0; i < totalCharts; i++) {
  var temp = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < 30000; j++) {
    temp.push({
      x: time + j * 1000,
      y: Math.random()
    });
  }
  data.push(temp);
}

var yAxises = [];
resize: {
  enabled: true
}

$('#container')[0].style.height = ((110 * totalCharts) + 200).toString() + 'px';

for (var i = 0; i < totalCharts; i++) {
  var yAxis = {
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3
    },
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    height: '100',
    top: (110 * (i + 1)).toString(),
    lineWidth: 2,
  }
  yAxises.push(yAxis);
}

var serieses = [];
for (var i = 0; i < totalCharts; i++) {
  var series = {
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Value ' + i.toString(),
    data: data[i],
    yAxis: i,
    boostThreshold:1,
    turboThreshold: 30000
  }
  serieses.push(series);
}

// create the chart
var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 0,
    allButtonsEnabled: false,
    buttonTheme: {
      width: 60
    },
    buttons: [{
      count: 1,
      type: 'second',
      text: '1S'
    }, {
      count: 5,
      type: 'second',
      text: '5S'
    }, {
      type: 'second',
      text: 'All'
    }]
  },
  scrollbar: {
    liveRedraw: false
  },

  _navigator: {
    enabled: true
  },
  navigatorButtons: [{
    onClick: function() {}
  }, {
    onClick: function() {}
  }],
  chart: {
    marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
    spacingTop: 20,
    spacingBottom: 20,
    zoomType: 'x'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Live random data',
    align: 'left',
    margin: 0,
    x: 30
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      millisecond: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%l:%M:%S.%L %p',
      second: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%l:%M:%S %p',
      minute: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%l:%M %p',
      hour: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%l %p',
      day: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
      week: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
      month: '%Y-%m',
      year: '%Y'
    },
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: "0.8em"
      }
    },
  },
  yAxis: yAxises,
  series: serieses,
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: "{point.y}",
    headerFormat: "",
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      turboThreshold: 30000,
      boostThreshold: 1
    }
  }
});


chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(data[0][1].x, data[0][2000].x, true, false);

var addToExtremes = 1;
var lastPlaybackTime = null;

function UpdateExtremesEverySecond() {
  var now = new Date();
  if (lastPlaybackTime === null) {
    lastPlaybackTime = new Date(now.getTime() - 1000);
  }
  var nextPlaybackTimeTicks = (lastPlaybackTime.getTime() + 1000 - now.getTime()); // + 1000;
  if (nextPlaybackTimeTicks <= 0) {
    nextPlaybackTimeTicks = 1;
  }
  lastPlaybackTime = now;

  console.log('nextPlaybackTimeTicks: ' + nextPlaybackTimeTicks);
  window.setTimeout(UpdateExtremes(), nextPlaybackTimeTicks);
};

function UpdateExtremes() {
  console.time('setExtremes duration');
  chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(data[0][1 + (1000*addToExtremes)].x, data[0][2000 + (1000*addToExtremes)].x, true, false);
  console.timeEnd('setExtremes duration');
  addToExtremes = addToExtremes + 1;
  if (addToExtremes < 10) {
    UpdateExtremesEverySecond();
  } else {
    addToExtremes = 1; //reset
  }
};

$('#add').click(function() {
  UpdateExtremesEverySecond();
});
$('#addTwo').click(function() {
  UpdateExtremesEverySecond();
});
```

This example is the closest I've been able to come to what we really have going on (there is quite a few events on our page and proprietary info too). However, it does demonstrates how slow setExtremes is with all of that data. The questions are:

Is there anything that can be done to improve the performance?

Am I using highcharts' boost functionality correctly?

Am I simply out of luck due to the amount of data I am dealing with?

Comment: 30000 data points for 1000 pixels is too much, have you tried downsampling your data? https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/13/Highcharts-Downsample

Comment: I added the highcharts-downsample.js library to my jsfiddle and added downsample: {threshold: 1000} and nothing improved...though I do not see "Downsample Error: Invalid data format! Note: Array of objects and Range Series are not supported"

Comment: I added the downsample library to my actual code and received no error like I did from jsfiddle but I did not see an improvement either. I'll have to revisit my jsfiddle to see what else is different

Comment: Hi @Eves, With `dataGrouping` your example is 3x faster: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1p4uzqoe/ However, I think the best solution would be to load only the `yAxis` or charts that are visible on the screen.

Comment: ppotaczek, perhaps I am missing something but...is there any difference in the javascript of the jsfiddle you posted vs mine? I do not see any data grouping in that jsfiddle nor any way to load only the visible on screen charts

Comment: Eves - I have removed the `boost` module, which will enable the `dataGrouping`.

Comment: Great, so if I go the route of only loading the parts visible on the screen are you talking about determining which specific yAxis are visible on the screen? If so how do you determine that? I know you can use getBoundingClientRect to get the bottom and top to compare that to the window's innerHeight and clientHeight but that requires an element and I do not know how to get the element specific to a particular yAxis

Answer (score 0):

The best way to increase performance in this case is to display only those series whose `yAxes` is visible on the screen. You can compare `axisLine` element with `window.innerHeight` or `document.documentElement.clientHeight`:

```
function areSeriesInViewport() {
    var series = chart.series,
        bounding;

    series.forEach(function(s) {
        bounding = s.yAxis.axisLine.element.getBoundingClientRect();

        if (
            bounding.bottom >= 0 &&
            bounding.top <=
            (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
        ) {
            s.setVisible(true, false);
        } else {
            s.setVisible(false, false);
        }
    });
    chart.redraw(false);
}

areSeriesInViewport();

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    areSeriesInViewport();
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m7p0a6xc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible

Comment: The performance on my jsfiddle example did improve some by hiding unseen yAxis. However in my actual page the improvement was not nearly good enough. Seems 30,000 data points is actually on the low end. I'm seeing numbers as high as 100,000. So performance is not so lovely even when only 3-4 yAxis are displayed.

Comment: Hi @Eves, Do you use `boost` module or `dataGrouping`? Maybe it is worth to reduce the number of points before creating a chart?

Comment: I tried both. Boost did not seem to do anything...though I did not try it with the limit of setting only visible yAxis. And for data grouping? I suspect I am not doing it quite right (though I am still trying). As for reducing the number of data points? Yes, I am looking into why in the world I have so many (we see little reason to have more than 6000 for a 10 minute window and yet I see nearly 100,000 for some charts).

Comment: Eves - The `boost` module works great with lots of data in a static chart. However, with this amount of data, the points will overlap anyway, so in your case `dataGrouping` from 'Highstock' seems to be a better solution. I think that you should also enable `turboThreshold` and pass the data as arrays.

Comment: Additionally, Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/neast08q/ Now the series are added or removed instead of hiding or showing, that is much faster.